# How to compute modular transfer function (MTF) from line spread function (LSF) with given discretization

Tags: fourier-transform, transfer-function

I have an optical system, which is commonly characterized by its point spread function. Somehow by the method, which resemble slanted edge method, I have end up with discretized line spread function of the system. I have it in array `lineSpreadfit` so that `len(lineSpreadFit)=2*tailFitLength+1`, where tailFitLength is something sufficiently long such as `1000pix` and the value `lineSpreadFit[tailFitLength]` correspond to the middle of line spread function. Pixels correspond to array elements 1:1.

Now I would like to make sure that my MTF calculation is correct, because in the literature there is always just "do FFT", but there seems to be a lot of caveats. So the first problem is I assume that FFT frequency $k$ shall be interpreted as `k lp/(2*tailFitLength+1)pix`, which depends on the discretization and is not optimal.  I prefer to visualize at least how many pixels do I need to produce line pair, so spatial amplitude.

My Python code is as follows. Did I fit correctly the frequency of FFT to lp/pix?

```
lineSpreadFit = lineSpreadFit/np.sum(lineSpreadFit)
mtf = np.abs(np.fft.fft(lineSpreadFit))
xfreq = np.arange(0, tailFitLength+1) # In lp/(2*tailFitLength+1)pix
plt.title("MTF of %s"%(ARG.inputFile))
pixelsPerLp = np.zeros(tailFitLength+1)
for i in range(tailFitLength+1):
    if i != 0:
        pixelsPerLp[i] = (2*tailFitLength+1)/i
plt.plot(pixelsPerLp[1:tailFitLength+1], mtf[1:tailFitLength+1])
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.xlim([2*tailFitLength+1, 2]) 
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Amplitude pixels per full cycle")
plt.show()
```

Moreover I would like to see the correspondence between MTF defined as a function of contrast with respect to [lp/pix] or in my case [pix/lp] and MTF defined by means of this FFT calculation. Can I show they are the same?